# error: invalid use of incomplete type 'tvbuff_t

Tags: plugins, makefile, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to build an old dissector with the new wireshark source and I'm facing this compilation problem and am not able to resolve it.

More log:

```
packet-xxx.cpp:467:7: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'tvbuff_t {aka struct tvbuff}'
In file included from ../../epan/proto.h:51:0,
                 from ../../epan/packet.h:29,
                 from packet-xxx.cpp:51:
../../epan/tvbuff.h:64:8: error: forward declaration of 'tvbuff_t {aka struct tvbuff}'
make: *** [packet-xxx.lo] Error 1
```

Comment: Does that type still exist in wireshark? Did it move headers and you need to add the correct include?

Comment: The headers still exist. <wireshark-src-dir>/epan/tvbuff.h

Answer (score 2):

The `tvbuff_t` was made [opaque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer), so accessing its members directly is no longer allowed in dissector code. In stead of `tvb->length`, use `tvb_length(tvb)` and so forth for any attributes you need to access.

This was answered on the Wireshark Q&A site at http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/27388.

Comment: Indeed. After coming back and looking at the error again I realized that was likely the problem I just hadn't formulated an answer about it yet (or looked to confirm my suspicions).