# Forward declaration error while trying to build wireshark dissector

Tags: gcc, build, g++, makefile, wireshark

In a .cpp file I have a particular extern "C" {} code.
When I try to build this file, I get an error of forward declaration.

```
In file included from ../../epan/proto.h:51:0,
                 from ../../epan/packet.h:29,
                 from packet-xxx.h:13,
                 from packet-xxx.cpp:8:
../../epan/tvbuff.h:64:8: error: forward declaration of 'tvbuff_t {aka struct tvbuff}'
```

Stuck in this for a while.
Any suggestions/clues?

Comment: Is that *all* the error message log says?

Comment: packet-xxx.cpp:101717:52: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'tvbuff_t {aka struct tvbuff}' ----- This is the first line. The reason I am interested in the compiler options is because I know for a fact that the above file was compiled successfully with a modified config file in wireshark1.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: invalid use of incomplete type 'tvbuff\_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213928/error-invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-tvbuff-t)

Comment: @Sudhir Are you trying to manipulate a `tvbuff_t` directly or inherit from the struct into another class? You _might_ be able to get something like that to work *for now* by just moving the definition of `struct tvbuff_t` back into the header. However, whatever you are doing on line 101717 probably won't work past the next update if you do (and there's no guarantee what you are trying to accomplish is still possible if the structure of `tvbuff_t` or its internal usage semantics have changed).